# make your eyes like a monk's eyes

Tags: idiom-requests

Imagine, a beautiful woman is sitting at a bar. A man keeps staring at her. Is there an idiom that the woman would use to ask the man to stop staring at her?

I know they usually say *keep your eyes to yourself*. But in my language, we have an idiom for that situation which literally translates to "make your eyes like a monk's eyes! ".

Is there an idiom like that in English?

Comment: As an idiom is defined to be generally accepted, you can't just invent one. They emerge. ELU does not deal in non-standard usages. Please remove the final sentence.

Comment: People certainly say *keep your **opinion*** or ***hands** to yourself*, but to my way of thinking, *keep your **eyes** to yourself* is about as weird as *keep your **ears** to yourself* (I'd rather express the relevant sense with ***Don't stare / rubberneck*** or ***Don't listen in / eavesdrop***). People also say ***Look away / Avert your eyes***

Comment: In movieland, if the "beautiful woman" is feisty enough, she'll probably say something like *Why don't you take a photograph? It'll last you longer.*

Comment: But I have hear keep your eyes to yourself in movies. It's also in Urban dictionary: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eyes%20to%20yourself